# Cross-browser scrollbar for div

Tags: html, cross-browser

I am trying to find a way to add a cross-browser compatible scrollbar to a div.

I've had to resort to using a mixture of two methods- see css below:

```
.div{
    /*-Only works for IE*/
    overflow-y:scroll;
    overflow-x:hidden;

    /*Works for all browsers except IE*/
    overflow: -moz-scrollbars-vertical;
}
```

The only problem I've found with this method is that the non-IE scrollbar moves the contents of the div across to accommodate and IE-only scrollbar doesn't.

Is there a better method anyone knows of?

Comment: `overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: scroll;` creates a vertical scrollbar for me (FF). What browsers should be supported? Btw, `<!--` and `-->` are not CSS comments, CSS uses `/*` and `*/`.

Comment: Do you find that the scrollbar pushes the div contents across for FF, but not for IE?

Comment: I'm supporting IE, FF, Chrome, Safari and Opera.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this will help.. however

```
div {
width: 200px; /* as example*/
height: 300px; 
overflow: auto; /* this will add scrollbars automatically if your div is larger than the specified dimensions */
}
```

cheers

Comment: This method still seems to have the same effect for me, where the div contents is resized to fit in FF but not in IE.

Comment: make sure there isn't any css rule overriding the div's style.. by the way I tested it on FF 3.6 and it works as expected ..

Comment: I can't see one. Does it behave the same in IE as FF?